# App does not working on older API but smoothly working on Higher API. Error: Google Play services missing or without correct permission?

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is working on Android 8.1 or higher smoothly but application crashes when try to run on Android 5.0, 6.0 or lower than 8.0 version. 
Tried to find the solution on internet but no relevant answer found.

Some time it shows some error on

**This is the Logcat report:**

```
04-16 16:20:22.416 3033-3059/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-16 16:20:22.760 3033-3063/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
04-16 16:20:22.762 3033-3063/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found
04-16 16:20:22.764 3033-3065/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found
04-16 16:20:23.009 3033-3059/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-16 16:20:23.104 3033-3033/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator, PID: 3033
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator:drawable/tape" (7f0700d4)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700d4 a=-1 r=0x7f0700d4}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:487)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:236)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:232)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
04-16 16:20:23.962 3033-3059/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-16 16:20:24.029 3033-3059/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-16 16:20:24.033 3033-3059/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
```

Showing an error on (MainActivity.java:41) as well. but why?

**My MainActivity.java File is here:**

```
package com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long backPressedTime;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel("Mynotification", "MyNotification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("general")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Connected to Firebase!";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Failed";
                        }
                        //Log.d(TAG, msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Email your feedback or suggestion", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Select Email option only!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Thread.sleep(2000);
                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                email.setType("plain/text");
                String[] address = {"silverfoxsofts@gmail.com"};

                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feed Back/Suggestion for MIXO - Construction Manager App");
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\nType your feedback or suggestion here.\n\n");
                startActivity(email);
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Privacy Policy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Privacy_Policy.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

*Manifests file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Volume_Calculation_Cylinder"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Area_Converter" />
        <activity android:name=".Area_Calculator" />
        <activity android:name=".Volume_Calculator" />
        <activity android:name=".Volume_Converter" />
        <activity android:name=".Torque_converter" />
        <activity android:name=".Length_Converter" />
        <activity android:name=".Lpm_to_Gpm" />
        <activity android:name=".Bar_to_PSI" />
        <activity android:name=".Accumulator" />
        <activity android:name=".SpareConsumption" />
        <activity android:name=".Slide_Sales_Reporting" />
        <activity android:name=".ServiceReport" />
        <activity android:name=".Hyd_vs_Concrete_Pressure" />
        <activity android:name=".Slurry_Calculation" />
        <activity android:name=".Pipe_Line_Calculation" />
        <activity android:name=".OnSIte_Pressure_Calculation" />
        <activity android:name=".Capacity_Of_Pump" />
        <activity android:name=".Friction_Factor" />
        <activity android:name=".DataLogger" />
        <activity android:name=".Ampacity" />
        <activity android:name=".VA_to_Watts" />
        <activity android:name=".MAh_to_Wh" />
        <activity android:name=".Kw_to_KWh" />
        <activity android:name=".KvaToWatts" />
        <activity android:name=".VoltageDrop" />
        <activity android:name=".WireGauge" />
        <activity android:name=".PowerFactor" />
        <activity android:name=".Electron_Volts" />
        <activity android:name=".Energy_consumption" />
        <activity android:name=".Amps_To_Voltage" />
        <activity android:name=".Joule_To_Watt" />
        <activity android:name=".AmpsToKVA" />
        <activity android:name=".kW_to_HP" />
        <activity android:name=".ampsToKW" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".Privacy_Policy" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/cap" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4613380677660687~9880768728" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**(Build.gradle)Project Level:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**(Build.gradle)App Level**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I already publish this app on google play store:
You can check it @ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the API you are targeting, the problem is in your toolbar

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

And the reason is

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator:drawable/tape" (7f0700d4)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700d4 a=-1 r=0x7f0700d4}
```

Comment: I had tried to replacing the drawable item by color code but still getting same problem.

Comment: if you are getting the same exact problem is dued to your xml layout, not google services, check the stacktrace

Comment: Trace reports are given above. Can you help me pls?

Comment: The trace reports are showing that the problem is caused dued your xml activity_main toolbar, not the google services

Comment: Why it is working on new devices? and why not in old devices?

Comment: Because the way you use certain methods in some api levels are deprecated in others and that introduce bugs

Comment: Now did solved some problem, now only one problem I have that is in XLM file. 
Please check the problem @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253621/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-navigation-navigationview

Comment: can you mark this answer as correct if it helped you ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, bro I should !

Comment: you can click the checkmark below the points bar in my answer , thanks

Comment: Problem is same

Comment: the problem is in my xml file, that is not matching with lower API. But still can get the exact problem of my code.

Comment: Some how navigation view is not inflating in lower API