# Error: inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, api, layout-inflater

Error: inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

My app working above API level 26 or higher but stoped working bellow API level 26.
Please help.

Why does XML returns error in inflating class, and stoped working in lower API level?

**Error Report:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator/com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
```

**activity.main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_bg_color"
        app:itemTextColor="#79847A"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ActivityMain.java ** here I'm using the XML file

```
package com.silverfoxsoft.concretepumpandconstructioncalculator;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long backPressedTime;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel("Mynotification", "MyNotification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("general")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Connected to Firebase!";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Failed";
                        }
                        //Log.d(TAG, msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Email your feedback or suggestion", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Select Email option only!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Thread.sleep(2000);
                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                email.setType("plain/text");
                String[] address = {"silverfoxsofts@gmail.com"};

                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feed Back/Suggestion for MIXO - Construction Manager App");
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\nType your feedback or suggestion here.\n\n");
                startActivity(email);
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Privacy Policy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Privacy_Policy.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show where are you using this xml file ?

Comment: i have update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line in your xml navview

```
 app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
```

Remove it and it should work.

Comment: problem is same!

Comment: the problem in my XML file, some how navigation view is not inflating in lower API level. For API-25 or higher is ok. Can you tell me the reason. I need the XML code, that can handle at least API-21

Comment: Sorry for late replay! That problem was due to unavailability of drawable items in v21 folder. that's why app crashes only on bellow API-24

Comment: @Anik, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late replay! That problem was due to unavailability of drawable items in v21 folder. that's why app crashes only on bellow API-24

Comment: please share v21 folder complete name and drawables folder structure.