# i cant link webview in main activity to content layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

here i try to add menu in my app screen , and when i run the app ,  its crash and show me this error :
`@layout/activity_main` does not contain a declaration with id `webview`

to understand my problem take a look to my code

activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this content layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



</LinearLayout>
```

part of my code from main activity (because its so long) , the error show with this (R.id.webview)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout LinearLayoutView;
    private WebView webView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    NavigationView nav_view;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer_layout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId())
                {

                    case R.id.nav_item01:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    case R.id.nav_item02:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_item03:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_item04:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_item05:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_item06:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_item07:
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this nav item 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    case R.id.nav_share:
                    {
                    ShareApp();
                    }
                    case R.id.rateapp:
                    {

                        RateApp();
                    }
                    case R.id.moreapps:
                    {

                       MoreApps();
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });



            WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webviewscreen();

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();


        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
```

errors :

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.example.webview, PID: 8114
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.example.webview/app.example.webview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at app.example.webview**strong text**.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700f6
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1013)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1021)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$Api23Impl.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:688)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:244)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:179)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:141)
             26 more
```

i watch many videos and they do exactly what I do , and its work with them

Comment: Check log cat and add the crash stacktrace with question .

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` class, you are setting the view as:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

However, your layout file `activity_main.xml` does not contain a `WebView` widget and hence you are getting that error.

Please try moving/creating the `WebView` widget inside the `activity_main.xml` file in order to resolve the error.

Please let me know in case you need anything else.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i tried that, and its didnt work , because this  made the webview appear with the menu. When I did this, another error appeared, which is the same problem as the webview, but this time with the banner ad

Comment: Hi @omarhariri: I see multiple issues based on the logcat messages you have posted in the question. can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253621/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-navigation-navigationview. If possible please post your build.gradle file as well

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml file you have to add include tag like this

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="your content layout like this @layout/content" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this include tag helps the MainActivity.java to find (R.id.webview) in the class and due to this include tag `android.view.InflateException` will resolve and your app run smoothly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From your log stacktrace, it indicates there is a problem with your `NavigationView`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.example.webview/app.example.webview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

And the main cause should be:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700f6

So there should be something wrong with your `@drawable/tab`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        ...
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab"
        ... />
```

You should check if the value of `@drawable/tab` is properly defined.